# Do melt flow rate and density tell you everything about pure HDPE?

Tags: plastics

I understand that melt flow rate and density can be used to classify HDPE. Does this mean that if I have the melt flow rate and density of an HDPE (with no additives), then I can know its other material properties?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as a rule the melt flow rate and density do tell you what the other material properties will be. This is why HDPE is often specified by those two properties.